# Side menu toggle transition effect?

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, toggle

I'm designing an app with Phonegap, which allows me to code with HTML5, CSS3 and JS. I created a toggle menu that when clicked shows and hides itself. This was accomplished by adding a "display: none" and "display: inline-block" property. I have read the others posts that reply to how to add transition to such property.  My issue is that I'm totally lost as in where I need to add the CSS property, because I have my .css file and a script tag in my HTML file.  Any thoughts please? :)

Here is my code:

```js
/* This script is written in my HTML file inside a <script> tag*/

/* My JS */
            function openSlideMenu() {
                $('#side-menu').css({"display": "inline-block"});
            }

            function closeSlideMenu() {

                $('#side-menu').css('display','none');

            }

        $(document).ready(function() {

        });

        app.initialize();
```

```css
.side-nav {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 z-index: 6000;
 position: absolute;
 height: 100vh;
 width: 70%;
 background-color: #7b66db;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, #7b66db 4%, #9673fb 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #7b66db 4%, #9673fb 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #7b66db 0%, #9673fb 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 0px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.49);
 -moz-box-shadow: 4px 0px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.49);
 box-shadow: 4px 0px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.49);
}
```

```html
<!-- MY IMAGES WON'T SHOW BECAUSE I HAVE THEM IN MY LOCAL FILES. THE IMAGE THAT SHOULD SHOW IS AN "X" ICON FOR CLOSE. -->

<!-- Side Nav Menu -->
        <div class="side-nav" id="side-menu">
            <div class="top-bar">
  
                <div class="vpay-logo-div">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="img/vpay-logo.png" class="vpay-logo" alt="Brand Logo">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="close-icon-div">
                    <a href="#" class="btn-close" onclick="closeSlideMenu()">              
                      <img src="img/close-icon.png" class="close-icon-nav" alt="Close Icon">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                  <li>List item</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <!-- /Side Nav Menu -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how to create an app with Phonegap but if you Jquery as I can see you can just put the toggle function [documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) when you click the button

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#button-open-and-close-menu').click(function(){
       $('#side-menu').toggle(200);
   });
});
```

You can also make it with the animate function [documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to make like a slide effect from the left

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#button-open-and-close-menu').click(function(){
        $('#side-menu').animate({width:'toggle',marginLeft:'0'},300);
   });
});
//CSS
#side-menu {
   margin-left : -100%;
}
```